# How to pass a struct including a array of primitive type in JNA?

Tags: java, c, jna

I'm a novice JNA developer so please forgive me if this question is trivial, but I'm struggling against dealing with C-lang struct object including an array of float with JNA. Currently I got a compile error.

I think the problem is the wrong way to initialize and assign FloatByReference instance (`mys.Weights`) to mystruct class instance (`mys`), and believe that Java code below should not be modified because JNAerator automatically generated it.

My C Code:

```
typedef struct
{
  int n;
  float *Weights;
} mystruct;

void testfunc(mystruct* mys){
  printf(mys->Weights[0]);
}

public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public static final String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME = "test";
    public static final NativeLibrary JNA_NATIVE_LIB = NativeLibrary.getInstance(CLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME);
    public static final CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary(CLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, CLibrary.class);
```

and Java:

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public static final String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME = "test";
    public static final NativeLibrary JNA_NATIVE_LIB = NativeLibrary.getInstance(CLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME);
    public static final CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary(CLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, CLibrary.class);


    public static class mystruct extends Structure {
        public int n;
        public FloatByReference Weights;
        protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("n", "Weights");
        }
        public mystruct(int n, JnaeratorTestLibrary.feature_t.ByReference Features, FloatByReference Weights) {
            super();
            this.n = n;
            this.Features = Features;
            this.Weights = Weights;
        }
        public mystruct(Pointer peer) {
            super(peer);
        }
        public static class ByReference extends mystruct implements Structure.ByReference {

        };
        public static class ByValue extends mystruct implements Structure.ByValue {

        };
    };
    void testfunc(CLibrary.mystruct mys);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mystruct mys = new mystruct();
    mys.n = 10;
    mys.Weights = new FloatByReference();
    // Compile error raises.
    mys.Weights = new float[4]; mys.Weights[0] = 1.0;

    testfunc(mys);
}
```

Compile Error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from float[] to FloatByReference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Pointer`, then use `Pointer.getFloatArray(0, n)` to extract the data you want.

You'll need to allocate `Memory` and use [`Memory.write()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#write(long,%20float[],%20int,%20int)) to write a Java primitive float array to native memory before assigning that memory to your structure field.

`FloatByReference` is basically a pointer to *one* allocated float.  JNAerator simply can't tell the difference between a pointer to a single float and a pointer to a buffer of floats (nor can a human without some additional context).